# How to save a data frame with with the split (explode) method in a separte row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to save a CSV-File but it doesn't really save the changes. That's my code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 data=pd.read_csv("Olympic.csv", parse_dates=["Birthday"])
 data['Birthday'] = data['Birthday'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

 data['Medaille'].str.split(', ')
 data.assign(Medaille=data['Medaille'].str.split(', ')).explode('Medaille')
```

The output of the `data.head()` is:

```
      Medaille
0     Gold   800m
1     Silver 600m
2     Bronze 300m
3     Gold   500m
4     Silver 500m
5     Silver 600m
6     Gold   400m
```

I wanted to save the CSV with the Method `data.to_csv("Save.csv", index=False`)

But after i saved it and looked at the changes again with the method `data.head()` it goes to the default changes (also inside of the saved CSV-File):

```
data.head()

     Medaille
0    Gold   800m, Silver 600m
1    Bronze 300m, Gold   500m
2    Silver 500m
3    Silver 600m
4    Gold   400m
```

Comment: Note that the first sentence of the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) on `assign` states: "Returns a new object with all original columns in addition to new ones." I.e., you need to re-assign the output (`data = data.assign(...)`), otherwise you just save the original dataframe.

Comment: Likewise, the line `data['Medaille'].str.split(', ')` does not change the original dataframe.